# MongoDB - Retrieve all formations that won and lost

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

Below is 1 of many documents in a collection:

```
_id:blaaaaaa
__v:0
user:blaaaaaa
opponent:"glen"
userFormation:"4-3-1-2"
opponentFormation:"4-5-1"
outcome:"win"
gameMode:"seasons"
```

I'm looking for a query that will return the number of wins and losses associated with a formation. Is this possible in MongoDB?

It should return something like this:

```
userFormation: 4-1-2-1-2
win: 3
loss: 2
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: No of win and loss is possible but what is that userFormation?

Comment: @PavanVora It's just a formation in football (soccer). Would it be a better to retrieve a larger result set and do the final calculations in javascript?

Comment: Here for each document the userFormation is different. How you would like to get it. And ya retriving larger result will be fine but I think that is not the best way. If you can't get it the result you want then you can go for larger result.